# C++ - syntax error: identifier

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I created a class "Player". In this class I declare an object "CollisionSystem", whose constructor looks like this:

```
CollisionSystem(Player *player, std::list<Rock*> *lRock, std::list<Water*> *lWater);
```

I made a pointer `CollisionSystem *pSystem` and in player's constructor I said

`pSystem = new CollisionSystem(pSprite, pRock->getRocks(), pWater->getWater())`

It now says "syntax error: identifier "Player". in the line, where I declare the constructor of CollisionSystem. Why does it say that (it says it 4 times, always for the same code line)

Comment: Does your `CollisionSystem` include the Player class through an `#include`?

Comment: How did you declare `pSprite`? You've posted incomplete code

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's better than describing the code in English.

Comment: @GillBates `CollisionSystem`and `Player`both include each other

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thank you ^^ This solved my problem!